# UIScrollView is using an unrelated UIViewPropertyAnimator when it shouldn't

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiviewpropertyanimator

I'm using a UIScrollView whose content is a simple UIView subclass whose size is set using auto layout and which uses drawRect: to render its content rather than having subviews of its own.

If the content (and the size) of the UIView changes then everything works as intended. The new content instantly appears and the scrollability of the UIScrollView enables/disables if the size of the content now needs / no longer needs scrolling.

However, if there's an animation going on somewhere else on the screen things no longer work as intended.

In that case the change to the UIView is animated along with that other animation.

So if that other animation takes say, 2 seconds, the new UIView content is instantly redrawn but  at a scale so that it fits in the old content's size. Then it animates the content, growing (or shrinking) over a period of 2 seconds so that at the end of the animation its size is what it should be.

The "interfering" animator in question is owned by a ViewController quite a bit further up in the food chain and the UIScrollView and its content UIView are never told about the UIViewPropertyAnimator.

The problem only happens if the content change overlaps the animation. If that other animation has completed (or hasn't started yet) the content in the scroll view is updated instantly.

Does anyone have insight into this, or perhaps could suggest a way to force UIScrollView and/or its content view to always do their own thing and not tag along for the ride if some unrelated UIViewPropertyAnimator is chugging along elsewhere?

EDIT: A bit of extra info

The animation code is older and originally made use of UIView.Animate and some swipe gestures were triggering the animation. In that case even if the animation and the content size change overlap (using the exact same repro scenario), the new (scrolled content) size appears immediately and doesn't get linked to the UIView.Animate animation. Swapping in UIViewPropertyAnimator code (and without any gesture recognizers getting involved) the problem is triggered and content size change becomes animated.